# Select a unique combination of two columns

Tags: mysql, qsqlquery

Sample data:

```
ProductID    PackingID
-------      ---------
1            2
1            2
3            2
3            2
1            1
2            1
3            2
```

I have the above sample data. What i want is to select the unique (not distinct) rows of the combination `productID` and `packingID`. In the above example the only matching results are

```
ProductID    PackingID
-------      ---------
1            1
2            1
```

These rows are the only unique combinations of `ProductID` and `PackingID` together. I do not want Distinct results because it will give me one of all the other combinations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT PRODUCTID,PACKINGID FROM DTEMP
GROUP BY PRODUCTID,PACKINGID
HAVING COUNT(PRODUCTID)=1 
ORDER BY 1;
```

You can try this one this is how i do in oracle ... to get the unique rows without using distinct.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT ProductID, PackingID
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY ProductID, PackingID
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

Comment: Wow I'm so sleep deprived I didn't even think of that

Answer (score 0):

your table should be like:

```
 uniqueID   ProductID   PackingID
   1          x            y
   2          x            y
   3          z            x
```

Query:

```
SELECT uniqueID,ProductID,PackingID
FROM yourtable
WHERE uniqueID IN
(
    SELECT MIN(uniqueID)
    FROM yourtable
    GROUP BY ProductID,PackingID
)
```